# An invariant submodule of a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, group-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and $S$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$. If $P$ is a finitely generated projective left $R[G]$-module then is the submodule of $S$-invariants $$P^S:= \{p\in P:g(p)=p\ \forall g\in S\}$$ a projective left **$R[G/S]$**-module?

We know that there is a $R[G]$-module $Q$ and a positive integer $n$ s.t. $P\oplus Q\cong R[G]^n$. So $P^S\oplus Q^S=(P\oplus Q)^S\cong (R[G]^n)^S\cong (R[G]^S)^n.$

Now is it true that $R[G]^S\cong R[G/S]?$ I'm not sure how to show this or if this is the way to proceed.

Also is this result true if $P$ is not finitely generated?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Now answered on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236904/an-invariant-submodule-of-a-projective-module

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236904/an-invariant-submodule-of-a-projective-module